# Invert color in Preview

Tags: macos, preview, image-editing

I used <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to invert the colors on an image. When I open the image in Preview then try to print it, the image does not print with the colors inverted.

Is there another way for me to do this?

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2019/07/27/how-invert-image-mac-preview/

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> keypress inverts the video signal of the display. It does not alter the 'true' colour properties of images, nor does it affect printing.

You can effect an inverse colour transformation to an image in Preview, using the method described here:

https://osxdaily.com/2019/07/27/how-invert-image-mac-preview/

Essentially, you pull up the `Tools > Adjust Color` window, then switching the position of the Black point and White point sliders in the Adjust Colors panel (drag the left pointer on the histogram all the way to the right, and the right pointer all the way to the left).

Note that the `Adjust Color` window will only popup for bitmapped files like JPEG/PNG/TIFF etc., so you will need to save each page of a PDF to one of those formats first for this to work, so may not be a good solution for 50-page long PDF's.  (You can then save back into PDF format, and combine into a single PDF with preview.)

Other photo editors are available, with better/easier controls and features.

Comment: brilliant!  worked perfectly for converting a white-on-black webpage to black-onwhite for printing (with less ink usage).